# How to capture audio in Ubuntu from a stereo device?

Tags: usb, sound, headphones

I have a stereo device on which I can play a casette tape (the old magnetic storage devices before CD's). I want to capure the audio from the stereo (from the headphone jack; the only possibility) and record it digitally with a Ubuntu computer (with just a headphone *out*put and USB connections).

How to do that?

I guess I need some external USB device to capture the audio and to be able to record it on the Ubuntu device. But what is the name of such a device?

Or is there another possibility?

Comment: Plug your tape deck earphone jack into your computer microphone jack, using the correct size connector, 2.5mm or 3.5mm, (may need an adapter for USB). Record with Audacity.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a USB Audio Interface. Not all of them work equally well on Linux though, it may be worth checking here if there is driver support:

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Main